# Give dynamic name in Report Header in crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, mvvm, crystal-reports-2008

I've one Crystal Report which gets generated on selection change of dropdown...
Everything is working perfect but One more thing I want to implement is dynamic Report Header(i.e. Text of dropdown should get displayed in Header).any suggestions....?

```
       public void FillMonthlySalesData()
    {
        _totalAmount = 0;
        foreach (SalesReportInfo SalesRecord in _salesReportViewModel.SalesmonthlyreportInfo)
        {
            DataRow objRowSales = _salesReturnreportDS.Tables["MonthlySalesTable"].NewRow();
            objRowSales["SINo"] = _mno++;
            objRowSales["Date"] = SalesRecord.SalesDate;
            objRowSales["Total"] = SalesRecord.Nettotal;
            _totalMonthlyAmount = _totalMonthlyAmount + SalesRecord.Nettotal;
             _month =  SalesRecord.SalesDate.Month;
             _year = SalesRecord.SalesDate.Year;
            _salesReturnreportDS.Tables["MonthlySalesTable"].Rows.Add(objRowSales);

        }
        DataRow objRow1 = _salesReturnreportDS.Tables["MonthlySalesTable"].NewRow();
        objRow1["NetTotal"] = _totalMonthlyAmount;
        objRow1["Month"] = _month;
        objRow1["Year"] = _year; ;



        _salesReturnreportDS.Tables["MonthlySalesTable"].Rows.Add(objRow1);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dt.columns.Add("ReportHeader");
for(int i=0;i<dt.rows.count;i++)
{
dt.rows[i]["ReportHeader"]=comboReportHeader.Text;
}
```

Try this one

Comment: I get the value in section Details, but it's not geting the vale in section Report header...i want to display in report header...

Comment: add ReportHeader field in DataSet which is used in crystalReport field

Comment: i am add it. But, when it use in report header, nothing displayed in the report. But it use in details section, it displayed currect value...i want this in report section...

Comment: your dt column name and crystalReport field name must be same. and crystal report header should be field from dataSet

Comment: It's correct......column name and crystalReport field name same and crystal report header is field from dataSet..

Comment: it should work...I also used same logic in my project and it works perfectly

Comment: is it displyed on the page header?

Comment: yeah..can you show me your c# code and crystal report by uploading screen shot

Comment: I want to display month and year in report header

Comment: ok..and the problem is that month and year are not displayed on crystal report right

Comment: yes.............not displayed on report header...But if field set in details section , its displayed

Comment: how can this possible? are you sure you have tried same field in header & detail section..because if it display in detail section then it should be displayed in header

Comment: what did you do then?

Comment: I  can not understand it. Is it my mistake or the crystal report?...anyway i change my  codes...i am not sure i get the answer..and one more doubt that is the field should string?anyway thanks for your support.